# Is there a way to generate kotlin dsl using data

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-dsl

We are using kotlin dsl to as a user friendly builder to take input and generate data. Is there a way to do the opposite of that ?
ie, convert existing data into dsl ?

Can this kotlin representation be converted to dsl ?

```
val person = Person("John", 25)
```

```
val person = person {
    name = "John"
    age = 25
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? convert 1st snippet to 2nd one?

Comment: You could easily make an Android Studio plugin that interacts with Kotlin code using the PSI

Comment: @GovindaSakhare yes to be precise, I am trying to convert existing objects to DSL representation.

Comment: @user please elaborate.

Comment: See [this](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html) on creating plugins. You can use an [editor event](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/editor_basics/editor_events.html?search=event) to turn Kotlin code into the DSL form

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're really crazy about `{` and some commas, below is an absolutely valid Kotlin code:

```kotlin
data class Person(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int
)

val person = Person(
    name = "John",
    age = 25
)
```

I seems really close to what you want and comes out-of-the-box.

Of course, you can achieve the syntax you want by writing some extra code, like:

```kotlin
import kotlin.properties.Delegates

data class Person(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int
)

class PersonDSL{
    lateinit var name: String 
    var age: Int by Delegates.notNull<Int>()

    fun toPerson(): Person = Person(this.name, this.age)
}

fun person(config: PersonDSL.() -> Unit): Person{
    val dsl = PersonDSL()
    
    dsl.config()
    
    return dsl.toPerson()
}

fun main(){
    val person = person {
        name = "John"
        age = 25
    }
    println(person) // Person(name=John, age=25)
}
```

But why do that?

Comment: isn't `with(person)` better choice here?

Comment: Probably you could go with `with`, but I decided to show the principle of making DSL like that. I'm not saying it's the only way.

Comment: @madhead I am trying to generate DSL for existing data.

Comment: In one line `PersonDSL().apply(config).toPerson()`